# WPF ContextMenu doesn't see dependancy property of user control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu, caliburn.micro

I have a user control (named mUserControl) with some textboxes, content of which is bounded to properties of a class (model), named Module. The user control itself has one custom dependancy property (ItemSource) of type Module. So I can bind content of textboxes to properties of the Module.

This user control is a part of a bigger View (HomeScreenView). I get easily access to ItemsSource from HomeScreenViewmodel. Everything works fine except a ContextMenu on textboxes. I get a binding error. ContextMenu doesn't see the ItemsSource property of the user control, whilst all other elements do that. I know, ContextMenu is on different visual tree. I've tried different ways to get this work, with no success. Any suggestions are welcome!

UserControl xaml (simplified for clarity):

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.Views.ModuleFrameView"
x:Name="mUserControl">
<Grid>
<TextBox x:Name="txt5" Text="{Binding ItemSource.Ch1SET, 
ElementName=mUserControl}" IsEnabled="{Binding ItemSource.IsEnbl_5, 
ElementName=mUserControl}" IsReadOnly="True"                        
TextAlignment="Center" ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
<TextBox.ContextMenu >
     <ContextMenu Name="cm">
             <MenuItem Header="Enable" cal:Message.Attach="cmEnable($source)" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="
{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ItemSource.IsEnbl_5, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}}"/>
     </ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
<!--...-->
```

ModuleFrameView has an ItemSource property defined in code-behind file:

```
public Module ItemSource
    {
        get { return (Module)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(Module), typeof(ModuleFrameView), new PropertyMetadata(default(Module)));
```

This DP of type Module:

```
public class Module : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _ch1SET;
    public string Ch1SET
    {
        get { return _ch1SET; }
        set
        {
            if (_ch1SET == value) return;
            _ch1SET = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Ch1SET);
        }
    }
private bool _isEnbl_5;
    public bool IsEnbl_5
    {
        get { return _isEnbl_5; }
        set
        {
            if (_isEnbl_5 == value) return;
            _isEnbl_5 = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsEnbl_5);
        }
    }
//...
//...lot of properties
```

Second user control (above mentioned bigger View)'s xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.Views.HomeScreenView">
<Grid>
    <ContentControl>
<loc:ModuleFrameView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemSource="{Binding ModuleArr[0]}"/>
<loc:ModuleFrameView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemSource="{Binding ModuleArr[1]}"/>
<!--...-->
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit latte but if your datacontext is set correctly, you don't need names and you can simplify like below (not tested) but a DP can be accessed directly  + "ItemSource" is wrong property name if you have just one element=> change to "CurrentModule"

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.Views.ModuleFrameView">
    <Grid x:Name="ROOT">
       <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentModule.Ch1SET}" IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentModule.IsEnbl_5}" IsReadOnly="True"                        
TextAlignment="Center" ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
<TextBox.ContextMenu >
     <ContextMenu>
         <MenuItem Header="Enable" cal:Message.Attach="cmEnable($source)" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=CurrentModule.IsEnbl_5, ElementName="ROOT"}"/>
     </ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

next to that, your HomeScreenView, need to be replaced by a list binded to collection of module, and define an item template to your loc:ModuleFrameView with "List ItemSource="{Binding ModuleArr}"

Answer (score 0):

`PlacementTarget` is a property of the parent `ContextMenu` so you should use `ContextMenu` as the `AncestorType` instead of `TextBox`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Enable" cal:Message.Attach="cmEnable($source)" IsCheckable="True" 
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ItemSource.IsEnbl_5, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
```